# Issue in Validation when updating the record : Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

## **My rule is like below. Please check the composite_unique in the below code**

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
      'SubCategory' => 'required|max:25|min:5|composite_unique:tblsubcategory,CategoryID',
      'CategoryID'  => 'required|min:1'
    ];
}
```

## **My update method is like below...**

```
public function update(SubCategoryRequest $request)
{
    $SubCat = $this->CacheCollection->getAllSubCategories($request->input('CategoryID'));
    $SubCategory = $SubCat->SubCategories->where('SubCategoryID', 1)->first();
    $SubCategory->SubCategory = $request->input('SubCategory');
    $SubCategory->CategoryID = $request->input('CategoryID');
    $SubCategory->save();
}
```

## **My Validator class is like below. Please check the composite_unique rule in below code.**

```
class ValidationServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot() {
        $this->app['validator']->extend('composite_unique', 
                                  function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
            // remove first parameter and assume it is the table name
            $table = array_shift( $parameters ); 

            // start building the conditions
            $fields = [ $attribute => $value ];                 

            while ( $field = array_shift( $parameters ) ) {
                $fields[ $field ] = \Request::get( $field );
            }

            // query the table with all the conditions
            $result = \DB::table( $table )
                         ->select( \DB::raw( 1 ) )
                         ->where( $fields )->first();

            return empty( $result ); // edited here
        });
    }
}
```

## **What's the problem**

When i try to update the record and don't edit anything and click on update button... I am getting the error that duplicate combination of SubCategory and CategoryID. I think validation code is done just for check before Inserting the new record. For update it is not working.

## **Below is the Schema of SubCategory Table**

```
CREATE TABLE `tblsubcategory` (
  `SubCategoryID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `SubCategory` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `CategoryID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `IsActive` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `tblsubcategory`
  MODIFY `SubCategoryID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

## **Below is Unique Key Constraint**

```
ALTER TABLE `tblsubcategory`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`SubCategoryID`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `UK_tblSubCategory_SubCategory_CategoryID` (`CategoryID`,`SubCategory`);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I did some manipulations in the boot function inside `ValidationServiceProvider` class. Below is what was done.**

```
class ValidationServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot() {
        $this->app['validator']->extend('composite_unique', 
                                  function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {

            $table = array_shift( $parameters );                
            $fields = [ $attribute => $value ];                 
            $columnName = null;
            $columnValue = null;                
            while ( $field = array_shift( $parameters ) ) {
                if(strpos($field, '#') !== false) {
                    $columnName = str_replace("#", "", $field);
                    $columnValue = \Request::get( $columnName );
                }
                else
                    $fields[ $field ] = \Request::get( $field );
            }

            if($columnName == null && $columnValue == null) {
                $result = \DB::table( $table )
                             ->select( \DB::raw( 1 ) )
                             ->where( $fields )->first();
            }
            else {
                $result = \DB::table( $table )
                             ->select( \DB::raw( 1 ) )
                             ->where( $fields )
                             ->whereNotIn($columnName, [$columnValue])
                             ->first();
            }                
            return empty( $result ); // edited here
        });
    }
}
```

**and Finally here is the `rules` function**

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
    'SubCategory' => 'required|composite_unique:tblsubcategory,CategoryID,#SubCategoryID#',
    'CategoryID'  => 'required|min:1'
    ];
}
```

**now let me explain what is happening in the above code**

In the rules function, you can check the last comma separated value is `#SubCategoryID#`. This was because my query was like below.

```
Select SubCategoryID from tblSubCategory 
Where (CategoryID = ? and SubCategory = ?) 
and SubCategoryID not in(?)
```

In this way I am getting to know what column to place in `whereNotIn` block. So, in my case, it was SubCategoryID value that is in `whereNotIn`. Finally in the validation function, # is being removed from the column Name.

Comment: Your use of `*` is bad coding practice